# GCM - Can't Receive Messages when Application is destroyed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on GCM I deployed GCM in my Application and it worked fine as it should, but that was a previous build now that I have some understanding of GCM I tried to integrate GCM on my new build. But I have encountered a strange issue perhaps it is something obvious that I am missing. But now I don't receive messages when application is destroyed (I am receiving messages when app is in foreground or in background). Also the older version is still receiving messages.

I have added receiver and services in manifest file.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.jadoo.jadooplus.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.jadoo.jadooplus.gcm.PromotionalListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.jadoo.jadooplus.gcm.services.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.jadoo.jadooplus.gcm.services.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

But I still can't receive messages. I have checked for incoming messages using Log but onMessageReceived is never invoked.

Here is my ListenerService

```
public class PromotionalListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    Log.d("Listener", "data=" + String.valueOf(data));

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {

        //  topics messages
        if (Config.isActivityActive) {
            Intent messageReceived = new Intent(GcmConfig.MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
            messageReceived.putExtra(GcmConfig.MESSAGE_LABEL, data);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(messageReceived);
        }
        else {
            //  Show a notification
            sendNotification(data);
        }

    }
}
```

Note: Please don't confuse this with Force Stopping an application.

Comment: You may also need to add the REGISTER permission to your action.<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />.

Comment: is your service is sticky? if not please check your service may your is destroying as app destroyed

Comment: @MustanserIqbal I will try that. But I have enough memory to go around.

Comment: @Devsil I had tried that but it didn't work. I apologize for upvoting your comment, but it was an accidental click. And apparently there is no way u can take it back.

Comment: @Abbas. No worries... Another thing to check is you have all the appropriate permissions declared in your manifest as well. <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.your.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.your.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Comment: @Devsil again didn't work.

Comment: @MustanserIqbal doesn't make any difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you declared the WAKE_LOCK permission? Also, do you get any log report from this that you could share? It might shed some more light on the issue. Also, you can post your issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) to get additonal help on this one.

Comment: @pointNclick I have added the WAKE_LOCK permission. But since the application is not crashing nor receiving any messaged when the application is destroyed so it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks guys issue resolved. I don't know how every change I made after unsuccessful atempt I reverted it, but I when I ran the code today no issues.
Also if anyone knows whether I ought to close the question or not? Since I am not facing any issues?

Comment: @Devsil Figured it out it was in the permissions I was missing `<permission android:name="com.jadoo.jadooplus.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />` but I still have a question about that. I wasn't using it in the previous manifest file either but it still worked excellent.
Any Ideas?